Asymptotic dimension of graph families representing each finite group
Frucht's theorem says every finite group is isomorphic to the automorphism group of a simple graph $G$ (with no loops, multiple edges or directed edges).
There has been interest in finding classes of graphs $\mathcal{C}$ such that $G$ can always be chosen to be an element of $\mathcal{C}$ in the above statement, i.e. for every finite group $\Gamma$, there is $G\in \mathcal{C}$ with $\Gamma = Aut(G)$. For example, we can let $\mathcal{C}$ be the sub-cubic graphs (i.e. maximum degree 3), but not the planar graphs (see below).
My conjecture is

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a class of finite graphs which is closed under
contracting edges. Suppose
that every finite group is isomorphic to the automorphism group of a
graph in $\mathcal{C}$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ has infinite Assouad-Nagata
dimension (and even infinite asymptotic dimension).

If true, then combining this with a result of Liu -- Assouad-Nagata dimension of minor-closed metrics and Distel -- Proper Minor-Closed Classes of Graphs have Assouad-Nagata Dimension 2 would imply a theorem of Grohe, Schweitzer and Wiebking -- Automorphism groups of graphs of bounded Hadwiger number, saying that minor-restricted classes cannot represent every finite group.
The assumption that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under contracting edges is essential; without this we could replace each edge of a graph in $\mathcal{C}$ by long enough paths to achieve $ASdim(\mathcal{C})=1$.

Hi Agelos, how do you view $\mathcal{C}$ as a metric space? (to talk about various dimensions of it)

@MikaeldelaSalle: each element of $\mathcal{C}$ is a metric space (a graph endowed with its standard metric, i.e. distance(x,y)=least number of edges in a x-y path). When defining $asdim(\mathcal{C})$, we want the bounds on the control function to hold uniformly over all elements of $\mathcal{C}$.
